# I want to find maximum counting value from using tabulate(MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, max

I need help to find maximum count value using tabulate. For example:

```
tabulate([1 2 4 4 3 4])
```

returns

```
  Value  Count  Percent
      1      1    16.67%
      2      1    16.67%
      3      1    16.67%
      4      3    50.00%
```

I want to get the maximum count and also the value that has maximum count or if possible I need all three columns corresponding to the maximum count: "4      3      50.00%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an output (`nargout == 1`), [`tabulate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html) returns a normal matrix, with which you can use [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html):

```
a = tabulate([1 2 4 4 3 4]); % Get output as matrix
[~ , maxi] = max(a(:,2));    % Find index of max count (column 2)
maxa = a(maxi,:)             % Row of a that correspond to max count
```

which returns

```
maxa =

     4     3    50
```

Then, if you want the string like the no argument form gives you, you can use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
maxs = sprintf('%g %d %.2f%%',maxa)
```

which returns

```
maxs =

     4 3 50.00%
```

Comment: i use max(a) with the other set of vetors/matrix and it returns max of each column which is not correlated at all.

Comment: I just edited my answer a bit. This version specifically looks for the row of the output `a` that corresponds to the maximum count column -rather than the maximum in any column. I believe that's what your question was asking.

Comment: it still not correct. how about if i use maxa = max(a(:,2)); then i get the max of 2nd column and then how to find the number in the first column that corresponds to maxa?

Comment: I optimized the answer a bit more to just find the index of the maximum of column 2 and use that -it's equivalent to what I had before.

Comment: How is it not correct? Are you trying this on other data? What doesn't work? What is the expected output?

Comment: My result shoul be "0   1607383   51.2977111417484" but using yours code i got "0    1.6074    0.0001" Any idea?

Comment: What input? Are you sure that there isn't a `1.0e+06 *` or something multiplying all of those numbers in your command window? Or is that the output of `sprintf`? Do you get the right answer before converting to a string?

Comment: yes, it is 1.0e+06 * like you said.. First i read and image and make it to be binary then i'm using bwlabel and finally i use tabulate. Anything i have to do? The result that i told you, i just copy from a.

Comment: I don't know what your data types are. `tabulate` converts everything to double I believe. This solution is pretty basic and I don't see any other issues with the finding the max count and corresponding row. You need to consider if your inputs are what they should be and if you properly determining the expected result. I think we should move any further discussion from the comments to chat if you still have issues.

Comment: horchler, how can i chat with you? I try to do this but i still cannot. I want your advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1 2 4 4 3 4]; % data

y = tabulate(x);
[m, ind_table]= max(y(:,2));

solution = y(ind_table,:)
```